# Restrict view/url to the current session in Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a form that lets you create a new site with Djangos built in Site module. I have setup a url, view and template for it. Everything is working as expected.

The user will go to the URL `/welcome/` when successfully created a site. But then I realized that everyone that tries to go to that URL will see the welcome content. Including Google. That is not what I want.

I want to restrict this URL to the current session and give a 404 page when others trying to go to that URL also for logged in users. I have looked at Djangos view decorators but haven't found one for my particular need.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

**To clarify:**

I would like to ONLY display `/welcome/` after the actual creation of the site. The user that CREATED this site will ONLY have permission to display that page. To others that tries to display the page it will raise a 404 (not found) error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you want to restrict a view for a certain site, you could use [`get_current_site()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#hooking-into-the-current-site-from-views).

```
current_site = get_current_site(request) 
if not current_site.domain == 'foo.bar.com':
    raise Http404
```

Use `request.user` to access the current user.

You could implement this check in your own view decorator or perhaps in custom Django middleware.

Comment: I added more info in the question now. I don't think I explained it thorough.

Comment: OK Thom Wiggers, I now edited again. Hope u understand me. Thanks!